# Git not adding recently unignored files

Tags: git

I modified my .gitignore to unignore a lot of files and folders.

I ran `git add .` and it added a bunch of them. I did `git commit` but I made a mistake so I aborted the commit. Now for the life of me I can't get git to see those ignored files again.

I did `git pull;git reset --hard origin/master` and everything was back to the way it was. But now when I change .gitignore, `git add` no longer seems to add anything but `.gitignore` itself. It doesn't add any of the recently unignored files.

Comment: Do a `git check-ignore -v` on one of those files, to check if a gitginore rule still applies.

Comment: @VonC I tried `git check-ignore -v somefile` and got nothing. It's strange because I thought you were onto something. I realized I had backed up my old .gitignore into the parent directory (without renaming it) of the project and thought maybe git was reading it. But I guess it wasn't. I even moved it somewhere else and still nothing is working.

Comment: @VonC  `git check-ignore *` doesn't even show anything...

Answer (score 0):

When you did the `git reset --hard origin/master` you reset all of the files in your working directory.  Then when you modified the `.gitignore` file, that became the only file that was added when you called `git add .`.

Comment: Yes, ok. But all those ignored files are still uncommitted aren't they? `.gitignore` was reset to its old state where it ignore a bunch of files. When I change it to only ignore a few, shouldn't `git add .` then scan for those new files?

Comment: What does `git status` tell you?

Comment: `git status` just tells me that only `.gitignore` is modified. Which is true, technically. But if I'm "up-to-date with origin/somebranch" then all of the files I stopped ignore are *not* up-to-date. I don't understand why they aren't being added.

Comment: ok, this is hilarious. Somehow I managed to delete all untracked files again. So of course `git add` isn't finding them. Now I remember at some point I did a `git pull` and/or a `git reset --hard origin/master` and for some reason I saw a bunch of `deleted xyz` scrolling by my terminal. I guess that's what that was.